# How to define HttpClient BaseAdress dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameter-passing, uri

I have an Asp.Net webpage written in c#. This webpage is communicating with a host on a server. The server adress is actually hardcoded in my controller methods as

```
 static PatientController()
        {
            //Create the HttpClient once and use it
            _httpClient = new HttpClient();
            _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9002/prom2etheus/v1/");
            _patientList = new List<Patient>();
            
        }
```

How can I configure the URI as a parameter, that a user can enter at the start of the UI? My problem is, that the host is running on a server, and my UI is running on the same server, but in a Docker container. So the IP of the host can change, and I don't want to hardcode the IP of the host in my controller method. Which is the better way to do?

Comment: You shouldn't declare an HttpClient for every controller instance. See [You're using HttpClient wrong and it's destabilizing your software](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). Instead of using HttpClient directly, I recommend [Flurl](https://flurl.dev/), which solves some of those issues for you. Then you can take in the base URL via method parameter or whatever other technique you want for obtaining that string.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I didn`t know flurl, which seems to be a good tool for that

Answer (score -1):

It depends. If you want the url to persist, then storing it in a database or a file is a good idea.

On the other hand, if it is okay to propt user every time the app starts, it could be stored in memory. This would jave the added benefit that, it would be much faster to read/write since there's no IO. There could be othet storage options such as third party storage provides too. In both cases, you would have to think about thread safety.

Comment: Thanks for that help. Can I store the URL also in a web.config file? Or should I prevent an own configuration file for that matter?